# Angular speed of a rod fixed on the ground

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

The question in my textbook is given as -

> If A meter stick held vertically with end on the floor and is allowed
>   to fall. The angular speed of the other end when it hits the floor if
>   there is no slipping?

The question is simple enough and I have no problem with the solution given as -

$\quad \quad \quad \frac{M\ g\ L}{2} = \frac {1}{6} ML^{2} \omega^{2}$

But I have a counter arguement.  What if I take a small element $\delta m$ on the top of the rod and equate it as -

$\quad \quad {\delta m\ gl}  = \frac {1}{2} \delta m\ l^{2} \omega^{2}$

Thus $\omega$ will be different in both the cases.

I can't seem to find out my error. Can anyone help me in finding it out?

Answer (score 1):

The moment of inertia of your element is $\delta m \,l^2$ but you are dealing with a rigid body composed of many such elements situated along the rod rigidly connected together.
So you must deal with all the elements as a whole.

If you combine all the elements by integration noting that the drop will not be $l$ for the other elements you will get the solution you started with.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the whole rod as a single system, you have conservation of mechanical energy because the only external force other than gravity is the reaction at the pivot which is fixed at the ground and therefore no work is done by it.

On the other hand, if you consider a $\delta m$ as a system, then there is external force (other than gravity) acting on it the the other parts of the rod. The contact points are moving and hence these will do work on $\delta m$ and therefore you don't have conservation of kinetic plus gravitational potential energy.